Error: Config file was not found at "/vercel/path0/.vercel/output/config.json"
When deploying an astro website to vercel, it keeps showing me this error:
Error: Config file was not found at "/vercel/path0/.vercel/output/config.json" at tb (/var/task/sandbox.js:395:1589) at async zze (/var/task/sandbox.js:407:35143) at async f_r (/var/task/sandbox.js:425:2334) at async m_r (/var/task/sandbox.js:425:2135)
I tried reimported vercel but it doesn't work. I were expecting that the website should be hosted.

Is there a possibility you could share a minimal repro? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
